# Create a variable to store a count for DATEDIFF greater than 3

Tags: sql, variables, count, datediff

This may be really simple and I'm probably overthinking it. I have to create a variable that stores  the number of employees who have been employed with the company for more than 3 years.

Here's what I came up with since the original table does not have the years stored, only a column with the hire date.

```
DECLARE @YearsEmployed int,
 @Plus3 int,
 @EmpCount int
 SET @YearsEmployed =   (SELECT DATEDIFF(YY,HireDate,GetDate())
    FROM employees)
 SET @Plus3 = @YearsEmployed > 3
 SET    @EmpCount = COUNT(@Plus3)

 SELECT @EmpCount
```

I've already gotten the "Incorrect syntax near '>'" error and I'm at a loss on how to proceed.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will give you count employees who have been employed with the company for more than 3 years:

```
       DECLARE @EmpCount int

       SET @EmpCount =   (SELECT count(DATEDIFF(YY,HireDate,GetDate()))
       FROM employees where DATEDIFF(YY,HireDate,GetDate()) > 3)

       SELECT @EmpCount
```

COUNT and the condition to pick employees who have worked for more than 3 years can be included within the query and stored in a variable rather using multiple variables and then getting count of those.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple query to me:

```
select count(1)
from employees
where HireDate < dateadd(year, -3, getdate())
```

Note I have opted for `dateadd` with the current date, rather than a `datediff` expression on the column value since the latter is not [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

---

As far as the code you have written the error comes from trying to assign the result of a boolean expression (`@YearsEmployed > 3`) to a variable. Furthermore, the query is `SET @YearsEmployed = ...` will fail if there is more than one row in `employees`. Additionally, I don't believe `COUNT()` can be used outside of a query - and even if it can, it's not going to do anything useful.